# Не получается сделать так, чтобы иконка меняла цвет самостоятельно

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить ошибку, хотел что бы при нажатии на кнопку у меня иконка мигала несколько раз, а в итоге иконка меняет цвет только при повторном нажатии на кнопку

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import random
def color():
    count=0
    while count<=3:
        count=count+1
        a = {1: "red", 2: "green", 3: "black", 4: "grey", 5: "yellow", 6: "blue", 7: "orange"}
        b = random.randint(1, 7)
        c = a.get(b)
        label = Label(bg=c, height="2", width="15")
        label.place(relx=.37, rely=.20)
root= Tk()
root.geometry("500x600")
root.title("Game")
root.configure(bg="white")
label2=Label(text= "Запомни цвет")
label2.place(relx=.4, rely=.12)
btn= Button(root, text="Начать игру", command=color)
btn.place(relx=.40, rely=.60)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У вас метка меняет цвет несколько раз, при нажатии кнопки. Это происходит быстро и глазу не видно, но если вы добавите в функцию print(c), то цвета распечатаются. Вам надо сделать задержку в изменении цветов, для этого лучше используйте after вместо while.